# Reset display defaults in KDE?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, kde

Bear with me, i'm a total Linux/KDE noob.

I recently set up my new install. Upon connecting my second monitor, it prompted me to choose between several display options. I choose "laptop only"  by mistake: my pc isn't even a laptop, so I'm unsure what this display option is meant to be.

Now, upon connecting my second monitor, my main goes dark and no image on my second. If I disconnect one of the monitors, the image resumes on the other.

I have tried the WIN+P menu, but unlike Windows, successive presses does not cycle trough the options. So, when my screen is black, I have no option of selecting another option such as extend. I have tried setting this in 1-display-mode, but it seems that only applies to 1-display-mode: even when I enable extend on the single monitor, attaching a second makes everything go dark.

Answer (score 1):

To solve it:

1. Press super (win) + p and release both
2. Press tab twice to select unify output ( 3 times for extend to left, 4 times for right)
3. Press enter